# What are the differences between a plain variable and a reference to it?

Tags: c++, reference

If I write:

```
int a = 5;
int& b = a;
```

in c++, (I have to be careful in how I ask this), can `a` and `b` be used completely interchangeably?  Or does `a` have some properties, restrictions, semantics, etc. that `b` doesn't, or vice versa?

I know that the templating machanism will detect the difference between a plain type and a reference type.  But, is there any other situation?

Comment: They're identical. Check with `typeid(a) == typeid(b)`.

Comment: Well, yes and no, depending on context. Best consult a tutorial (e.g. https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html), as those are more suited to explain the basics than an SO answer.

Comment: And a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) usually beats a tutorial.

Comment: The only big important difference is when the `a` goes out of scope, `b` (if still around) will be a dangling reference.  A small difference *may* be performance, but before stressing about reference overhead performance impact:  **profile** your optimized build — optimizers can do amazing things, and may eliminate the reference machinery.

Answer (score 0):

A reference is just an alias for the variable it is referencing.  Once a reference is bound, anything you do to the reference is applied to the referenced variable.  So yes, for all intents and purposes, they are interchangable.